# Program overflows on large struct array value

Tags: arrays, struct, segmentation-fault

The code is an implementation of the Gift Wrapping Algorithm. The input file is of the form 'X Y Z' on each line, and I don't need to consider the Z co-ordinate. The code works fine for smaller N like 100000 but gives segmentation fault for larger N value. Can some one explain me the reason for it?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define N 200000

struct Point{
    double x,y;
};struct Point p[N];

int ori(struct Point p1, struct Point p2, struct Point p3);

int main(){
        FILE *fp,*fp2;
    fp2=fopen("out.txt","w");
    int i=0;
    fp=fopen("sample.txt","r");
    if(fp==NULL){
        printf("File not found!\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    double g;
    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
        fscanf(fp,"%lf %lf %lf",&p[i].x,&p[i].y,&g);

    int l=0;
    for(i=1;i<N;i++){
        if(p[i].x<p[l].x){
            l=i;
        }
    }

    int base=l,q;
    int chullin[N];
    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
        chullin[i]=-1;

    while(true){
        q=(base+1)%N;
        for(i=0;i<N;i++)
            if(ori(p[base],p[i],p[q])==1)
                q=i;
        chullin[base]=q;
        base=q;
        if(base==l)
            break;
     }
     int cnt=0;
     int a[26];
     for(i=0;i<N;i++)
        if(chullin[i]!=-1){
            a[i]=i;
            fprintf(fp2,"%f %f %d\n",p[i].x,p[i].y,i);
            cnt++;
        }


    return 0;
}

int ori(struct Point p1, struct Point p2, struct Point p3){

    int val=p1.x*(p2.y-p3.y)-p1.y*(p2.x-p3.x)+(p2.x*p3.y-p3.x*p2.y);
    if(val==0) 
        return 0;
    if(val>0)
        return 1;
    else return -1;
}
```

Comment: Because for N = `100000`  array size will be too large to accommodate in stack-segment use malloc/calloc for dynamic memory allocation.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not in the array `p`, but in the array `chullin`. Try to dynamically allocate the array, using the malloc function:

```
int *chullin = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*N);
// do whatever you want with chullin
free(chullin);
```

**Edit:** I will try to explain the cause of the Segmentation fault. When you create a non-dynamic array inside a function, it is allocated in the *heap*. The *heap* has limited size, so when you declare a large array, the heap overflows. When you use `malloc`, you dynamically allocate the array, which means that it is allocated in the *stack*. The *stack* has much bigger size than the heap, so you are able to create larger arrays. Global arrays are also allocated in the stack, that's why you needn't allocate them dynamically...

**Edit[2]:** Array `a` has size `26`, which means that when N is larger than or equal to `26` you will be accessing invalid memory locations, causing segmentation fault.

Answer (score 0):

you are totally overflowing the int array 'a' or at least accessing non-existent values within the array, which is on the stack... if chullin[i] != -1 for more than 26 points... or if chullin[i] where i>25, you are writing randoms on the stack.

```
 int a[26];
 for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    if(chullin[i]!=-1){
        a[i]=i; //problem here.
        fprintf(fp2,"%f %f %d\n",p[i].x,p[i].y,i);
        cnt++;
    }
```